# Updating the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have the determinant of a matrix $A$, whose entries are polynomials.  If I set one entry in the matrix equal to $0$, what is the fastest way to recompute the determinant?  Do I have to compute it from scratch?  Is there an easy way to represent the determinant of the new matrix in terms of the determinant of $A$?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I just found this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma